# Property 'layout' does not exist on type 'FC<WrapperProps>'. in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, compiler-errors

I am getting above error in my _app.tsx file . I am trying to use multiple layout which is normally working but typescript is giving error

here are the code

```js
import Layout from '@/components/layouts'
import NoLayout from '@/components/layouts/NoLayout'
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import { Nunito } from 'next/font/google'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { CompProps, WrapperProps } from '@/lib/utils'


const layouts: Record<string, React.FC<WrapperProps>> = {
  L1: Layout,
  L2: NoLayout,
};

interface CustomAppProps extends AppProps {
  Component: React.FC<CompProps>;
}

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: CustomAppProps) {
  const SelectedLayout = layouts[Component.layout || 'L1'] || (({ children }) => <>{children}</>);

  return (
    <div className={nunito.className}>
      <SelectedLayout>
        <Component {...pageProps} otherProps={Component.otherProps} />
      </SelectedLayout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and this is my utils.ts file

```js
export type CompProps = {
  footer?: boolean;
  style?: string;
  layout?: string;
}

export interface WrapperProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  otherProps?: CompProps;
}
```

but in my _app.tsx i am getting this typescript error

```js
Property 'layout' does not exist on type 'FC<WrapperProps>'.
Property 'otherProps' does not exist on type 'FC<WrapperProps>'.
```

Code is working fine but typeScript is the issue
i am not getting why i am unable to resolve this error, Also I am new to TypeScript please guide me

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? Because `Component` is a `React.FC`, so it doesn't have any props attached. But if there is some default props you can use them by using `Component.defaultProps`. Is this what you want ?

Comment: I want to pass layout and otherProps from each pages and based on that Layout will change for example i donot want navbar and footer in signup page so i can pass Signup.layout = "L2" and NoLayout will apply. It is already working in normal react but with Typescript it is giving issue

Answer (score 0):

Finally after spending sometime i found the issue and here are the solution for it.

first we need to define type of layouts

```js
const Layouts = {
  L1: Layout,
  L2: NoLayout,
};
type LayoutKeys = keyof typeof Layouts;
```

second we need to define type of component by extending AppProps and using nextjs NextComponentType and NextPageContext

```js
import { NextComponentType, NextPageContext } from 'next'


interface CustomProps extends AppProps {
  Component: NextComponentType<NextPageContext, any, any> & {
    Layout: LayoutKeys;
    otherProps: WrapperProps
  };
}
```

using this it will be a valid typescript code and need to change further in code but it was the main thing that i was missing.